# call .js file in joomla template

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a joomla template.
I've loaded jquery with this code in my index.php:

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
```

and then I created animate.js in js folder that includes this script:

```
<script> jQuery("#content").ready(function(){

jQuery("#content").animate({opacity:'0.4'});

}); </script>
```

and I added

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="templates/basicjoomla3.0template/js/animate.js"></script>
```

in head section of index.php but it doesn't work.
When I use my script in body tag of index php it works successfully but when I want to load it from js file it doesn't work.
What should I do now?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that your `animate.js` is loaded after `jquery loads` or try this,

**PHP:**

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework',  true, true);
followed by your plugins:
// some plugin located at _basePath/js
JHtml::_('script',$this->_basePath.'js/animate.js', false, true, false, false);
```

Remove the `script tags`from `animate.js`

```
jQuery("#content").ready(function(){
   jQuery("#content").animate({opacity:'0.4'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, your path to the file looks wrong

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/templates/basicjoomla3.0template/js/animate.js"></script>
```

Also, you dont need the  tags in the js filE